# Hide Rows in Excel based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multiple selection, Option buttons, that change the value of cell D7 from 1 to 5, depending on choice. I want to unhide rows 16 to 26 if value is 1 and hide them if it's different, and so on for every other value.

But I can't even get this to work at all, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Update: If I change the cell value, nothing happens, but if I delete all contents and add a value it gives: "Argument not optional", and it highlights this part of the code for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Excel.Range)
```

Thank you

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If IsNumeric(Target) And Target.Address = "$D$7" Then
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case 0 To 90: Cell_Hider
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Sub Cell_Hider(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("$D$7").Value = "1" Then
        Rows("16:26").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("16:26").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) please [edit] and improve your question.

Comment: I dont understand. Nothing happens when I change values, therefor it's not working.. I'm not sure how else I was supposed to phrase it..

Comment: Well telling that it doesn't throw any errors is already more than not telling. That means your `Worksheet_Change` never excecuted as it should immediately throw an error. Make sure the event code is placed in the correct worksheet (the one you change a value at). Also make sure you have events enabled `Application.EnableEvents` must not be false.

Comment: ah, I understand, let me try that and edit the post with what I get. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your procedure `Cell_Hider` needs an argument but your code calls it without argument `Case 0 To 90: Cell_Hider`
2. You call `Cell_Hider` if the value is between 0 and 90 then that procedure needs the value to be `1` to show the rows and 0 or 2 to 90 will hide them. If you put 100 in that cell nothing happens at all. Sounds not like what you expect to me.
3. `"1"` is text not a number!

Something like the following would work:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If IsNumeric(Target) And Target.Address = "$D$7" Then
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case 0 To 90: Cell_Hider Target
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Sub Cell_Hider(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = 1 Then
        Target.Parent.Rows("16:26").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Target.Parent.Rows("16:26").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Even though it doesn't look logic to me and I'm not sure what you are exactly trying to achieve.

Note that you can shorten it to

```
Sub Cell_Hider(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Parent.Rows("16:26").EntireRow.Hidden = Not Target.Value = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

### Hide/Unhide Rows on Cell Change

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = Me.Range("D7")
    
    If Intersect(sCell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If IsNumeric(sCell.Value) Then
        HideRows sCell
    End If

End Sub

Sub HideRows(ByVal SourceCell As Range)
    If SourceCell.Value = 1 Then
        SourceCell.Worksheet.Rows("16:26").Hidden = False
    Else
        SourceCell.Worksheet.Rows("16:26").Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```